# IPython only work for one version of Python in Anaconda(Win), how to solve?

Tags: python, anaconda

I use Anaconda Prompt to install another version of Python3 and the Jupiter Qtconsole and Ipython as the image shows . But it only works for one version; ones with 'py36' don't work when clicked on. Thanks for your answer if possible.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGDVf.png)

Comment: Please share for which version it works, and which version you need it for.

Comment: @bathe if you like to work with python 2.7 version, kindly create a conda environment by reading this [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html#create-a-python-2-7-environment).

Comment: Version 3.6 can work in cmd. But the IPython and Qtconsole don't react.Version 2.7 works on both. I wanna find a way to use both versions.

Comment: @bathe i found this [blog](https://thinkingvirtually.blogspot.in/2017/08/anaconda-environment-setup-import-tensorflow-solved.html) post about anaconda navigator by which you can install qt console for 2.x / 3.x. Just read it and create environment for 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @JosePraveen I installed the Qtconsole by this way before but it failed to work. It just flash for a moment and disappear. Pity.